# Mi crud no me permite agregar registros, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: php, html

Soy nueva en este mundo y estoy haciendo un sitio web para que los alumnos de una escuela consulten sus calificaciones.

El caso es que para los administradores creé un crud, este sitio lo entregué hace un tiempo ya completo y solo tenía un campo por materia (p.e. en MateI se mostraba la calificación que el alumno obtuvo en Matemáticas I) y funcionaba bastante bien.

Sin embargo me pidieron que esta vez tenga 3 campos por materia, uno para el ordinario, uno para el extraordinario 1 y otro para el extraordinario 2, y así lo hice, pero a la hora de agregar nuevas calificaciones no me permite, al final del segundo código dice que si la consulta es verdadera, redirija al crud, y si no, muestre "Datos no editados", la cuestión es que esto es lo que me muestra siempre y según yo, todo está bien, no sé si estoy pasando algo por alto, incluso hasta reescribí el código sin éxito alguno.

No sé si alguien detecte mi error, todos los demás botones (mostrar, editar y eliminar) funcionan a la perfección.
Este es el código del formulario donde se escriben los datos:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Agregar Calificacion</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="bg-black p-2 text-white text-center">Agregar calificacion</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="../Insertar/insertarDatosCalif.php" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Clave Calificacion</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ClaveCalificacion">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Matricula</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Matricula">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Matemáticas I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="MatematicasI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportMateI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportMateI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Quimica I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="QuimicaI">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportQuimI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportQuimI"placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Geografia</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Geografia">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportGeo" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportGeo" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Introduccion a las Ciencias Sociales</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="IntroduccionalasCienciasSociales" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportIntCS" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportIntCS" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Informatica I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InformaticaI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportInfI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportInfI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Taller de Lectura y Redaccion I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TallerdeLecturayRedaccionI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportTallerLyRI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportTallerLyRI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Ingles I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InglesI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportIngI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportIngI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Matemáticas II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="MatematicasII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportMateII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportMateII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Quimica II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="QuimicaII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportQuimII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportQuimII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Biologia I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="BiologiaI" placeholder="Ordinario"">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportBiol" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportBiol" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Historia de Mexico I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="HistoriadeMexicoI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportHistI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportHistI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Informatica II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InformaticaII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportInfII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportInfII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Taller de Lectura y Redaccion II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TallerdeLecturayRedaccionII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportTallerLyRII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportTallerLyRII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Ingles II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InglesII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportIngII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportIngII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Matemáticas III</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="MatematicasIII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportMateIII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportMateIII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Fisica I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FisicaI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportFisicaI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportFisicaI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Historia de Mexico II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="HistoriadeMexicoII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportHistII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportHistII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Metodologia de la Investigacion I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="MetodologiadelaInvestigacionI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportMetodI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportMetodI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Literatura I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LiteraturaI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportLitI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportLitI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Ingles III</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InglesIII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportIngIII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportIngIII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Matemáticas IV</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="MatematicasIV" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportMateIV"  placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportMateIV" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Fisica II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FisicaII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportFisicaII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportFisicaII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Ecologia y Medio Ambiente</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="EcologiayMedioAmbiente" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportEcologia" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportEcologia" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Estructura Socioeconomica de México</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="EstructuraSocioeconomicadeMexico" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportEstruc" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportEstruc" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Ingles IV</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InglesIV" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportIngIV" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportIngIV" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Individuo y Sociedad</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="IndividuoySociedad" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportIndividuo" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportIndividuo" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Administración I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AdministracionI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportAdminI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportAdminI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Contabilidad I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ContabilidadI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportContaI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportContaI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">Economía I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="EconomiaI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportEconI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportEconI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Informatica III</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InformaticaIII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportInfIII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportInfIII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Introduccion a la Mercadotecnia</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="IntroduccionalaMercadotecnia" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportIntMerca" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportIntMerca" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Filosofia</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Filosofia" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportFilosofia" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportFilosofia" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Administración II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AdministracionII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportAdminII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportAdminII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Contabilidad II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ContabilidadII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportContaII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportContaII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">Economía II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="EconomiaII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportEconII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportEconII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Informatica IV</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InformaticaIV" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportInfIV" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportInfIV" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Derecho Mercantil</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DerechoMercantil" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportDerMer" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportDerMer" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Probabilidad y Estadistica</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProbabilidadyEstadistica" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportProbyEst" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportProbyEst" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Modulo I</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ModuloI" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportModI" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportModI" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Modulo II</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ModuloII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportModII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportModII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Modulo III</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ModuloIII" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportModIII" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportModIII" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Modulo IV</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ModuloIV" placeholder="Ordinario">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportModIV" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportModIV" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Modulo V</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ModuloV">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OportModV" placeholder="Extraordinario 1">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SegundaOportModV" placeholder="Extraordinario 2">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Observaciones</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Observaciones">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Agregar</button>
            <a href="../CrudCalif.php" class="btn btn-dark">Regresar</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

No me está permitiendo incluir el código de donde el formulario realiza la acción, pero lo dejaré en un comentario o en otra pregunta que se llame igual + "Parte2"

Comment: Al parecer en comentarios tampoco puedo y stack overflow no me deja publicar hasta dentro de 40 minutos, por favor si alguien está realmente interesado en ayudarme, le pido que me tenga paciencia y vuelva más tarde o que me contacte por mensaje en una página de facebook llamada "Developer Cloud" con el logo de una nube y por ahí le mando todo:(

Comment: Aplica el concepto: "Divide y vencerás". Utiliza un ejemplo mínimo verificable. Probablemente el problema esté en la ejecución de las llamadas a la base de datos, quizás las variables no tengan el nombre adecuado y por lo tanto, no se guardan como se espera; sea como sea el caso, mientras editas la pregunta, agrega "echo" para que veas lo que se va ejecutando paso a paso. Aquí unas recomendaciones generales para la estructura de preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 (ignora el meme) Saludos.

Comment: En la [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/606843/80870) (deberías borrar esta) encontré que no coincide la cantidad de columnas y valores en la consulta `INSERT`, la cual se podría cerrar por ser un caso de errores tipográficos. De todas formas estás haciendo un esfuerzo innecesario al pintar manualmente ese formulario, y crear una consulta de 132 columnas. Si tuvieras una tabla para las materias eso se puede (y se debe) hacer de forma automática.

Comment: @aeportugal como se hace eso? La verdad no se me ocurrió una mejor solución pero si está muy pesado que haya tantas columnas:(